# Convert IEnumerable(Of Object) to class that Implements IEnumerable(Of Object)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using VB.NET, I have ths class

```
Public Class MyCollectionClass
  Implements IEnumerable(Of MyClass)

  Public Property MadeThisClassCuzINeedToSetThis() As String
  ' code here 
End Class
```

I want to do this, but get an exception saying I can't do this cast.

```
Dim objColl As MyCollectionClass
objColl = CType(IEnumerable(Of MyClass), MyCollectionClass)
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think End Class is being treated as string?

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you maybe you should remove the C# tag - I can't see any C# here!

Comment: Doh!  Thx, C# was auto-suggested.  Looks like it was removed.

Answer (score 1):

See this [VB.NET/C# casting cheat sheet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5044/Cheat-Sheet-Casting-in-VB-NET-and-C) or the [documentation on `CType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx). The major problem is that the first parameter should be the instance to convert, not its type. This should work:

```
Dim myEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of MyObjectClass) = New MyCollectionClass()
Dim objColl = CType(myEnumerable, MyCollectionClass)
' objColl's type is inferred As MyCollectionClass
```

(note that as [`MyClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3b35kyk.aspx) is a keyword, and I assume you actually have a different class name there, I changed it to `MyObjectClass` in my example)

Comment: Thx, checking it out.  Yes, my class isn't MyClass :)